# Combine model and boolean variable in expressionProperties - Formly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I want to set formly form fields disabled value based on model properties and boolean variable. This doesn't seem to work

```
expressionProperties: {
    'templateOptions.disabled': 'model.advancePayments && !model.deposit' || vm.acquisitionCancelledFlag
}
```

It works but the `|| vm.acquisitionCancelledFlag` doesn't make any difference

`vm.acquisitionCancelledFlag` is true but the field isn't disabled

I have also tried

```
'templateOptions.disabled': '(model.advancePayments && !model.deposit) || vm.acquisitionCancelledFlag'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent some time on this but figured out I can do this instead so I'm sharing it with people who might need it. Not the most elegant but works

```
expressionProperties: {
    'templateOptions.disabled': function(viewValue, modelValue, scope) {
        return (scope.model.advancePayments && !scope.model.deposit) || vm.acquisitionCancelledFlag;
    }
}
```